# My Textarea won't input text

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have been writing web code for a few years now and I am stumped. I am writing basic CSS/HTML and my textarea won't input text. my title is there and after double clicking on it, my cursor should indicate it is ready to type.

Any ideas?

**My css**

```
.postForm {
    float: right;
    width: 580px;
    height: 80px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding-top:30px;
    left:-30px;
}
```

**My Html**

```
<div class="postForm">
<form action="profile.php?id=<? echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST">
<textarea style="resize:none;font-family:Comic Sans MS; font-size:12pt;overflow: hidden;" id="post" name="post" class="auto-clear" rows="1" cols="60" title="Publish your thoughts...">     
</textarea>
<input style="position:relative;margin-left:450px;margin-top:-66px;" type="image" name="send" value="Post" src="post.png" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is accepting input.  Put your cursor in the textarea and hold down any key for a few seconds. It will eventually wrap down.  The problem is caused by the overflow being hidden.  Also `postForm` floating the element right is not helping matters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the value parameter on textareas, but do this:
`<textarea>example text</textarea>`

Comment: Looking at Kevin's answer and looking at the question again, I might have misunderstood the question. But the fact that the thread starter used the value parameter (for filling the empty textarea) still resides.